# Woocommerce empty cart button. "Are you sure?"

Tags: javascript, popup, woocommerce, cart

I have added an [empty cart] button to my Woocommerce cart page.

Great.

I would like to add a pop up to ask the user "Are you sure?"

In case they shop for two hours, and then hit this button by mistake.

I think this is custom JavaScript here.

Lets pretend the button has an id of `myButton`.

Comment: [`confirm()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: Here is the html wordpress generated for my empty cart button:

`<form method="post" action="">

<input class="button" type="submit" value="Empty Cart" name="empty_cart">

</form>`

here is my javascript attempt. 

`document.getElementByName("empty_cart").onclick=fuction(){
  
    confirm("Are You Sure ?");
}`

going to keep cracking, but any further advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your markup in your comment, try this:

```js
document.getElementsByName("empty_cart")[0].onclick = function(e) {
  var choice = confirm("Are You Sure ?");
  if (!choice) {
    //Cancel submit
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Empty Cart" name="empty_cart">
</form>
```

You were using `getElementByName` and `fuction`; neither exist.  To make small mistakes like this much easier to spot, have the **Console** tab open in your browser's developer tools while working on Javascript.  It spits out `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByName'`.

Comment: THANKS!
I'll start trying Console, I've mostly just been using fire-bug for css stuff.

Comment: Definitely check out `console.log(anything)` and `console.dir(anything)` to easily see all the available properties and functions of an object.  The console is extremely powerful, and I'd be lost without it!